# Initial search and multiple checkboxes to filter results in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, search, razor, filtering

I'm relatively new to **MVC 4** (**Razor**) and am coding a simple web application that allows users to search a single table database and filter the search results using checkboxes.

I am currently implementing a rather large number  of if/then statements that start with checking which one of three search boxes is populated (only one search button for ease of use on three search boxes was requirement)

Then, I check if any of the 10 (yes, ten!) individual checkboxes are selected and were populated (each checkbox is a filter for different columns in the table).

At the bottom of the rats nest of each nested if statement, I build a query. 
Then, in the final outer if statement, I take the built query and run it.

My question is, is there a better, faster and more efficient method to do this than I am currently using. 
My concern is that this application will most likely grow and require more filters, thus needing exponentially more nested if statements to check which filters were selected to search.

If this is the case, then all well and good, but if there is a better design, then I'd rather use that, than attempt to maintain this growing monster.

Platform is IIS Server .Net 4.5.1 utilising Linq to SQL to a 2012 SQL Server database. Standard MVC 5 .Net Razor

```
            if ((countryBox == "true") && (regionBox == "true"))
            {
                // Build query string

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                {
                    //incorporate searchString
                }
                else
                {
                    //searchString empty
                }
            }
            else if (regionBox == "true")
            {
                // Build query string
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                {
                    //incorporate searchString
                }
                else
                {
                    //searchString empty - set references to segmentBox search
                }
            }
            else if (countryBox == "true")
            {
                // Build query string
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                {
                    //incorporate searchString
                }
                else
                {
                    //searchString empty
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                {
                    // Build query string
                }

            }



            //return View(references.ToList());
            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(references.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

Comment: Why you need checkboxes? Can't you just use `Nullable` Types at server side to understand which boxes are filled? `MVC` `Binding` allow such things.

Comment: It might help if you could show us an example of your code, and the concerns you're trying to address.. right now it's too nebulous to really understand what your problem is.  You also haven't even mentioned what database technology you're using... are you using ADO.NET? EF?  Linq-to-SQL?  Micro-ORM?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys - I've added the code to the above and explained a little better in the edit